# How to uninstall a module in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

I have two modules installed:

```
Cro::HTTP:ver<0.7.4>
Cro::HTTP:ver<0.7.5>
```

And I want to keep `0.7.5` only. Don't know how to uninstall the lower version one.

Comment: You should be able to do it using `zef uninstall`, including the version number. Did you try that? https://www.learningperl6.com/2016/12/15/quick-tip-30-uninstall-a-perl-6-module/

Comment: I reinstalled my Rakudo Star, and use `zef install .` instead. I will try your answer if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
zef uninstall "Cro::HTTP:ver<0.7.4>"
```

(The quotes are important.)

Comment: Both work on my system (Linux):
$ zef uninstall "Unix::errno:ver<0.0.2>"
===> Uninstalled from /home/claudio/.perl6
Unix::errno:ver<0.0.2>:auth<cpan:ELIZABETH>
$ zef uninstall 'Unix::errno:ver<0.0.1>'
===> Uninstalled from /home/claudio/.perl6
Unix::errno:ver<0.0.1>:auth<cpan:ELIZABETH>

Comment: thanks, it does work now, with errors:`WARNING: unhandled Failure detected in DESTROY. If you meant to ignore it, you can mark it as handled by calling .Bool, .so, .not, or .defined methods. The Failure was:
Failed to remove the directory '/Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/short/42832B74025148AE494D735B0EB7559AE2B37D17': Failed to rmdir: directory not empty`

Comment: It looks like zef won't remove directories that are not empty. This is a sane default. For modules though, where no user data is expected, I think a 'rm -rf'-like behaviour would be OK. Maybe, create an issue to discuss it at https://github.com/ugexe/zef/issues ?